# Stream_get_contents not working after upgrade the PHP to 5.4.16

Tags: php

i have a PHP script , it contains stream_get_contents as below

```
$command= ‘show configuration system host-name;show interface descriptions’;
$handle= ssh2_exec($connection , $command);
#ini_set(‘max_execution_time’, 100); // added to reduce run time
$result= stream_get_contents($handle , 90000);
```

it was working fine on PHP 5.1.6
after i upgrade the PHP to 5.4.16
the stream_get_contents part is not working

can you help me please ?

Comment: Did you have some errors ?

Comment: Are those quotes `‘` and `’` in your code?

Comment: @Inazo , no i have no error

Comment: @brombeer , yes to take the command as is , and it's working normally 
the issue is with get contents only